# What's good copy to indicate addition, deletion and updation of employee data?

Tags: copywriting

We are creating a section in the our software that shows all the addition of new employees, deletion of employees who left the company and updates in the personal details of any employees. I am not able to think of good copy for this; should "Changes" work?

Comment: What about "Employee management"?

Comment: Is this one page with all of the new hires, departures, and changes? Or is this on the personal detail page for each employee?

Answer (score -1):

What about a general "Updates" or "New"? I would think even the addition or deletion of employees constitutes an update in itself.